# ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleImputer'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I try:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer()
imputed = pd.DataFrame()   
imp.fit_transform(Final_df201911)
```

but I get the error:  ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleImputer'

So I did:

```
conda update anaconda
```

It does all the downloading but then says, (in the anaconda terminal):

```
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.4.10-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
```

What do I need to do to get SimpleImputer? I am using scikit-learn version 0.19.1

Comment: try `from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer`

Comment: @warped It says:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.impute'  I'm guessing my sklearn module in anaconda is out of date.  But I get this PermissionError.  Whats that about?

Comment: What happens if you do `from sklearn import *`? just want to check if sklearn is installed at all.

Comment: @warped still same error :/

Comment: So it seems like you do not have scikit-learn installed. Go to the command prompt and try `conda install scikit-learn`. Then retry importing in python

Comment: Scikit-learn is installed, but there is no module named impute.  I check the documentation myself.  so I guess the version I have is correct.  But I can't update conda environment or any of the packages in anaconda prompt of of a permissions issue.  Since I am running on Windows and there is no 'sudo' command I dont know how to get around this @warped

Comment: so, `import sklearn` works without error?

Comment: What version of scikit-learn is installed? I.e., check `conda list scikit-learn` and add that output to your question.

Comment: @warped that is correct

Answer (score 4):

> I am using scikit-learn version 0.19.1

In this version there is only `Imputer` (https://sklearn.org/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html`)

---

`SimpleImputer` appeared in 0.22.

---

Try to install the latest version:

```
 pip install -U scikit-learn
```

And then use:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

Source: https://github.com/mindsdb/lightwood/issues/75